# Count number of childs and remove some

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm trying to count the number of childs in my firebase db, and check to see if there are 100. If so, then first 30 should be deleted. Here is my code. I'm not exactly sure if I should be using the .remove() here, but I put it there just so you could get an idea of what I am trying to do

```
// counts number of childs
    myDataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var count = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(function () {
            count++;
        });
        // if childs are == 100, remove the first 30
        if (count == 100) {
            myDataRef.remove( /* first 30 */ );
        }
    });
```

And a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y920s63h/

Hope I've been clear! Thanks.

Comment: does the counting part work, or do you need help in that too?

Comment: `snapshot.length` ... ?

Comment: The counting doesn't seem to be working, even with `snapshot.length`

Comment: [numChildren](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html) might be what you are looking for. As far as your code goes, you probably want to confirm that `snapshot` is an Array and not an Object (in which case `forEach` would not be defined). `snapshot` will be an Array if all the children of `myDataRef` are numeric, and an Object otherwise. It would be good to check your console to see if any errors are happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Web API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/), there is a [numChildren()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html) method available on each snapshot. That seems like the obvious first choice for obtaining a count.

The API docs also show that .remove() doesn't take any arguments; so there's not going to be a way to do any sort of `.remove( /* first 30 */ );`.

One might be tempted to try `.limit(30).remove()` to grab the first 30 and do a remove on those, but the Query object returned by limit() doesn't support the remove() method, unfortunately.

Instead, a combination of numChildren() and forEach() seems like the best approach:

```
myDataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    if( snapshot.numChildren() >= 100 ) {
       var i = 0;
       snapshot.forEach(function(ss) {
          ss.ref().remove();
          // returning true causes forEach() to stop iterating
          // so we can use that to only grab 30
          return ++i == 30;
       });
    }
});
```